# When update eclipse, it turns to another version

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I was using eclipse IDE for java Developers, then a notification for update comes through, I've accepted it, everything is ok, restart needed, ok.
after opening, I've shocked that it became IDE for Web Developers, and all my projects became full of errors, and can't make a new java project.
I can't just download another version of eclipse for java ee, because I have a lot of plugins installed, and many configurations made.
How I can return back to the previous version?

Any suggestions please

Comment: What was the old version number? What is the new version number?

Comment: the old version was 4.7.2, and the new version is 4.7.3a

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download and install the older version of Eclipse again:

- Don't try to reinstall on top of your existing installation.  Move or copy the existing Eclipse installation directory somewhere else before you start.
- I would also advise making a backup of your workspaces **before** you do anything else.  It is unlikely that the upgrade / downgrade will do any damage, but you can't be too cautious.

The errors that you are seeing are likely to be due to a simple Eclipse configuration problem, or maybe a problem with versions of third-party plugins.  If you told us what the errors were, someone would be able to tell you how to fix them.  Then you can use the newer version of Eclipse.

---

> I can't just download another version of eclipse for java ee, because I have a lot of plugins installed, and many configurations made.

Actually, neither of those things prevent you from doing that.  Downloading and reinstalling will be inconvenient ... but it is probably your best option.

Note that you could either download and install the new version of Eclipse, or you could download and install the version you were using previously.

Comment: I'v downloaded a new version from here
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen3a
the package name downloaded is "eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64.zip"
the extracted folder is a portable exe, so when I open it, it shows "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers" !!!
I think that there is something wrong somewhere

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you think that is wrong.  Look at what is in the download package: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen3a

Comment: Because it is for "Web Developers" not for "Java Developers", so when I click File>New... I found Static web project & Dynamic web project and so on, not relative to java projects.

Comment: That's an odd way to look at things.  Most people would say "Oh that's nice.  I can do my browser-side and server-side development work with the same Eclipse IDE installation!"   Anyhow, if you want to do Java EE development, this download is the one that is most suitable for you.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's no matter. I suggest to you use [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy) based on Eclipse 3.**; You don't have to deal.

Comment: You suggest using a legacy IDE, not to mention the question doesn't specify Spring at any point.

Comment: how is that no matter?, I can't work with java in eclipse any more!!

Comment: I already suggest you an eclipse, your workspace and projects does not change. You'll continue to work with your current projects. These are very close.